# MVC Session Variables in ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

How to use `Session Variables` in the `ApplicationDbContext constructor`. I want to pass 2nd parameter of the constructor from Session variable.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider, IDisposable
    {
 public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname, string connString = HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnString"].ToString())
            : base(connString)
        {            
            SchemaName = schemaname;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
        }
```

}

It gives me error at `HttpContext` that 'HttpContext does not exist in the current context'. Even if i have the namespace already added for this class.

Comment: Its because you are trying to call your HttpContext outside the HttpContext pipeline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application/_static/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application1.pdf What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for parameter should be compile-time constant (should be known at compile time). `HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnString"].ToString()` of course cannot be known at compile time, so you cannot use it as default value for `connString` parameter.

What you can do is create another contstructor:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider, IDisposable {
    public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname, string connString)
        : base(connString) {                
        SchemaName = schemaname;
        ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname)
       : this(schemaname, HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnString"].ToString())
    {            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i use cookie values?

Comment: Problem is not with session itself, but with how default values to _any_ methods work. I've updated answer with an option to resolve this.

Comment: I have used `using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))            { ..  }` more than 200 methods already.

Comment: @Anup updated once again, this time it should fit your requirements.

Comment: When i run the application, it gives me error :- `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 92:         public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname)
`

Comment: Well then your `HttpContext.Current`, or `HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnString"]` is null (no "ConnString" is session), but that's completely different story.

Comment: It was all working well but it started getting crashed where i have used Threading in background. When Thread runs in background it gets the Session as null. Is there any way i can handle null sessions in the above answer code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155360/c-sharp-mvc-handling-nulls-in-applicationdbcontext-constructor-parameters