# C# MVC Handling nulls in ApplicationDbContext Constructor parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been using Session Value in the ApplicationDbContext Constructor. But in my big application somewhere i have used Threading which runs in background. And when that Threading method hits the ApplicationDbContext Constructor it doesn't get the Session Value as request is already completed. I get null reference exception, so the Application crashes.

Following is `ApplicationDbContext` Constructor Code :-

```
public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname, string connString = "")
            : base(connString)
        {
            SchemaName = schemaname;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname)
            : this(schemaname, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnStringName"].ToString())
        {
        }
```

How to handle null sessions in the above constructor?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname, string connString = "")
            : base(connString ?? whateverDefaultConnStringName)
        {
            SchemaName = schemaname;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
        }

  public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname)
            : this(schemaname, System.Web.HttpContext?.Current?.Session?["ConnStringName"].ToString())
        {
        }
```

Comment: @Anup if you use C# version 6 or higher - this should compile: "System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.Session?["ConnStringName"]?.ToString()"

Answer (score 0):

That is a poor abstraction, do not put anything related to the http context in the constructor of the `DbContext` especially the `HttpContext.Current` if you are using mvc/web api.

What you should be doing is using an IoC (DI) framework like [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/). Create an execution context type (with matching interface) that has the `HttpContextBase` injected into the constructor and then extract the connection string you want to use from the `Session`. Register your `DbContext` type to have your `Execution` type injected into its constructor and initialize the connection string from it. That will give you nice SoC (seperation of concerns), code is no longer dependent on the executing thread context, and allow for easier unit testing.

There are many tutorials out there on how to setup IoC with MVC and many IoC frameworks to choose from.